# C# - Try-Catch-Finally on Return

Tags: c#, return, try-catch

I have the following code:

```
public DataTable GetAllActiveUsers()
{
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand getAllActiveUsersCommand = new SqlCommand(getAllUsers, connection);

                SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(getAllActiveUsersCommand);
                dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);

                return dataTable;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);

                return null;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Which basically get's the active users I have on my database. But can someone explain to me whether the `Finally` Block will be executed if it successfully runs the `try` block and returns the DataTable??

Thanks

Comment: You can always just breakpoint it.

Comment: You need to check connection state (is open) before closing. To avoid error from `finally` block.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes.

As stated here: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx)

> Typically, the statements of a finally block run when control leaves a
>   try statement. The transfer of control can occur as a result of normal
>   execution, of execution of a break, continue, goto, or return
>   statement, or of propagation of an exception out of the try statement.

But finally block is not *always* executed. You can read Alex Papadimoulis's anecdote [here](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/My-Tales)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it does.
The finally block will be executed whether there is a return statement or an exception thrown in the `try {} catch()` block.

Answer (score 3):

finally block is always executed.

you should Dispose in finally block. Because, dispose also closes the connection and disposes unmanaged memory resources.

```
finally
{
    connection.Dispose();
}
```